# How to get access token via Postman with Authorization Code Grant Type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot REST service. I use OAuth2 with Keycloak, and Authorization Code Grant Type.

I want to access some endpoints via Postman. I see under *Authorization* for selection `OAuth 2.0`, selecting it provides many fields.

When I do have the access token, for example I write it to the IDE output console, I can add it to *Current Token* section:

- *Access Token:* (dropdown, selected `Available Tokens`)
- C&P the access token value into the input field
- *Header Prefix:* `Bearer`

I can then access my endpoint by clicking the *Send* button.

But when I don't have the access token from the IDE console output, I have to configure all the other fields and then use the button *Get New Access Token*.

I configured the fields as follows in the section *Configure New Token*:

- *Grant Type:* `Authorization Code`
- *Callback URL:* `<emtpy>`
- *Authorize using browser:* `not selected`
- *Auth URL:* `http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth`
- *Access Token URL:* `http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token`
- *Client ID:* `<myclientid>`
- *Client Secret:* `<myclientsecret>`
- *Scope:* `openid` \
- *State:* `<empty>` \
- *Client Authentication:* `Send as Basic Auth header` (or `Send client credentials in body`)?

Also under *Authorization* I selected

- *Type:* `OAuth 2.0` \
- *Add authorization data to:* `Request Headers` (or `Request URL`)?

I'm not sure for *Authorization Code Grant Type* if the field *Add authorization data to* and *Client Authentication* are relevant, but something has to be selected there.

I must have configured something wrong or missing something. When I click the button *Get New Access Token*, a Keycloak window pops up with title *Sign in to myrealm* and error messsage:

> We are sorry
> Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Is it because the field *Callback URL* is empty? In this setup, what is the *Callback URL* (`redirect_uri`)? I assume it must callback to Postman, as this is the client who accesses the backend endpoint.

My backend REST service runs on port `8181`, Keycloak on `8180`, another frontend accessing the backend REST service on `8080`, Postman (I don't know on which port), on Lubuntu.

Comment: Not answering your question, but as a potential workaround you could register Postman as a separate client having "Direct Access Grants" enabled.

Comment: I don't know if your idea is also a valid solution, but my answer seems a bit more straight forward using just the Postman features. I only added the Postman redirect_uri in my existing client in Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is pretty simple once understood:

If one selects `Authorize using browser:` `Postman` will open a new tab in the web browser where one can then see the `redirect_uri` `Postman` uses in the address field.

This `redirect_uri` must be specified in Keycloak as an additional redirect url.
The rest of my configuration in `Postman` is OK as is, it works fine.

If one deselects `Authorize using browser:` then specify the `redirect_uri` in the given input field above it.

I have only tried it with the `redirect_url` `Postman` uses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a registered redirection URI, see [Authorization code](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#authorization-code):

> **Authorization code**
>
> Authorization code grant type requires the user to authenticate with the provider—an authorization code is then sent back to the client app, extracted, and exchanged with the provider for an access token to authenticate subsequent requests.
>
> To use authorization code grant type, enter a **Callback URL** for your client application (which should be registered with the API provider), together with various details provided by the API service including **Auth URL**, **Access Token URL**, **Client ID**, and **Client Secret**.

and [Requesting an OAuth 2.0 token](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#requesting-an-oauth-20-token)

> - **Callback URL:** The client application callback URL redirected to after auth, and that should be registered with the API provider. If not provided, Postman will use a default empty URL and attempt to extract the code or access token from it. If this does not work for your API, you can use the following URL: `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback`
>
>   - **Authorize using browser:** You can enter your credentials in your web browser, instead of the pop-up that appears in Postman by default when you use the **Authorization code** or **Implicit** grant type. Checking this box will set the **Callback URL** to return to Postman. If you opt to authorize using the browser, make sure pop-ups are disabled for the callback URL, otherwise it will not work.

See also:

- [OIDC Clients](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_oidc_clients)
- [Redirect URL Registration](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-registration/)
- [Oauth2 Postman browser Callback URL is not working as expected](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9390)